# Ways for images displaying from web page on IOS and Windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem.

I have a few images and all of them are from my iphone4. I put them on my web page and run on Mac or iphone or ipad. All of them are fine.

But when I run them on windows, some are portrait and some are landscape. I tried chrome on windows and chrome, safari on IOS. No matter what browser I use, the problem is still there.

I rotate the portrait to landscape by transform rotate property and it fix under windows platform, but ruined under IOS side.

Could someone give me a hand?

Cheers!

Comment: You need a script that will get the EXIF camera data and rotate accordingly on the fly for you. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might not be done inside html/css/js, but I take it all of them should work.

1. Take the images and give them other extensions without losing quality. This might reset or erase data in these images that makes them horizontal or vertical.
2. Take a screenshot of each and remake them. This one seems flawless to me.
3. Get some software that changes what they tell the browser they are
   (horizontal or vertical).